# How to make async call inside another async method in Webflux?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Explanation of the question is bit a long. Kindly take a minute and help!

I have two http calls which will give the following data.

1st http request call will return `<Mono<List<Chips>>`

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "redlays"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "yellowlays"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "kurkure"
  }
]
```

`Chips` Model is

```
@Data
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Chips {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

2nd http request call will return `Mono<ChipsDetails>` based on `Id`

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "color": "red",
    "grams": "50"
}
```

`ChipsDetails` Model as below,

```
@Data
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ChipsDetails {
    private int id;
    private String color;
    private String grams;
}
```

I have done the Implementation using Webflux. Here I have used three models which are `Chips`, `ChipsDetails` and `ChipsFullDetails`.

Model `Chips` will have two attributes `id` and `name` then Model `ChipsDetails` will have three attributes `id`,`color` and `grams` whereas Model `ChipsFullDetails` will have combination of `Chips` and `ChipsDetails` attributes which are `id`, `name`, `color` and `grams`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/chips")
public class ChipsController {

    @Autowired
    ChipsService chipsService;

    @GetMapping
    public Mono<List<ChipsFullDetails>> getAllChips() {
        return chipsService.getChips()
                .map(f -> {
                            List<ChipsFullDetails> chipsFullDetails = new ArrayList<>();
                            f.forEach(a -> {
                                ChipsFullDetails chipsFullDetail = new ChipsFullDetails();
                                chipsFullDetail.setId(a.getId());
                                chipsFullDetail.setName(a.getName());

                                chipsService.getChipsDetails(a.getId())
                                        .subscribe(b -> {
                                            chipsFullDetail.setColor(b.getColor());
                                            chipsFullDetail.setGrams(b.getGrams());
                                        });
                                chipsFullDetails.add(chipsFullDetail);

                            });
                            return chipsFullDetails;
                        }
                );
    }
}
```

Here `chipsService.getChips()` will return `Mono<List<Chips>>` This is the 1st call and `chipsService.getChipsDetails(a.getId())` will return `Mono<ChipsDetails>` This is the 2nd http request call.

The result of the implementation will be `ChipsFullDetails`

```
@Data
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ChipsFullDetails {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String color;
    private String grams;
}
```

The problem is `ChipsFullDetails` returns null for `color` and `grams` attributes which we are getting from the 2nd http call even though it is subscribed inside.

How to achieve when Second Http call i.e `chipsService.getChipsDetails(a.getId())` depending on the result of 1st http call (`chipsService.getChips()`) in asynchronous way?

Is this possible to achieve without blocking both the calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd transform the initial `Mono<List<Chips>>` into a `Flux<Chips>` first, so that you can `flatMap` on each element, e.g. something along those lines:

```java
public Mono<List<ChipsFullDetails>> getAllChips() {
    return chipsService
            .getChips()
            // Mono<List> to Flux:
            .flatMapIterable(Function.identity())
            // flat map on each element:
            .flatMap(this::buildChipsFullDetails)
            // Flux back to Mono<List>:
            .collectList();
}

private Mono<ChipsFullDetails> buildChipsFullDetails(Chips chips) {
    return chipsService
            .getChipsDetails(chips.getId())
            // once you get both chips and details, aggregate:
            .map(details -> buildChipsFullDetails(chips, details));
}

private ChipsFullDetails buildChipsFullDetails(Chips chips, ChipsDetails details) {
    // straightforward synchronous code:
    ChipsFullDetails chipsFullDetail = new ChipsFullDetails();
    chipsFullDetail.setId(chips.getId());
    chipsFullDetail.setName(chips.getName());
    chipsFullDetail.setColor(details.getColor());
    chipsFullDetail.setGrams(details.getGrams());
    return chipsFullDetail;
}
```

Comment: `flatMapIterable(Function.identity())` shows compile error. If i remove this line it works.

Comment: @RenceAbi Are you sure `chipsService.getChips()` returns `Mono<List<Chips>>` and not a `Flux<Chips>` already then? If it _does_ return `Mono<List<Chips>>`, make sure `Function` comes from `java.util.function` (you may be importing the wrong one).

Comment: This solution is working without removing `Function.identity()`. But if i remove `Function.identity()` and make the return as `Flux<Chips>`  also working. But i dont understand how both ways are working

Comment: @RenceAbi Basically, you need to work on a `Flux` here, so that you can `flatMap` on each element, and only then build a `Mono<List>` with the aggregated results. Ideally, `ChipsService#getChips()` returns a `Flux` directly, so that you can `flatMap` straight away. If it returns a `Mono<List>` though, you need to first transform it into a `Flux` thanks to `flatMapIterable`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and answer. I appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

I basically disagree with the idea of working with a `Flux`, though I admit I have it as well.

I would say that if you want to get details for a list of chips then you should make an endpoint that does that. Then it will be a single call.

For you original question, there is a way to do it without going to `Flux`, but it reads a bit funny:

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Chip>> chipList = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Chip>>() {};

public Mono<List<ChipDetails>> getChipDetails() {
    return webClient.get().uri("chips").retrieve().bodyToMono(chipList).flatMap(chips -> {
        return Mono.zip(chips.stream().map(chip -> webClient.get().uri("chipDetails?id="+chip.getId()).retrieve().bodyToMono(ChipDetails.class)).collect(Collectors.toList()), details -> {
            List<ChipDetails> chipDetails = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Object o : details) {
                chipDetails.add((ChipDetails) o);
            }
            return chipDetails;
        });
    });
}
```

This uses `Mono.zip` to create a sort of batch request out of each of the `Chip` entries in the list executes them all at once. `Flux` will probably end up doing more or less the same thing but not really.

If you just make the endpoint you need, then:

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ChipDetails>> detailsList = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ChipDetails>>() {};

public Mono<List<ChipDetails>> getChipDetailsReal() {
    return webClient.post().uri("chipDetails").body(webClient.get().uri("chips").retrieve().bodyToMono(chipList), chipList).retrieve().bodyToMono(detailsList);
}
```

This approach avoids repeated calls to the same endpoint and is doing what you want.

I'm not a fan of using `Flux` when you really mean `List`. A `Flux` is a streaming thing with backpressure and sophisticated capabilities whereas a List is just a List.

Comment: one needs to understand that this approach, uses a `stream#map`, which is a synchronous operation, handled by one thread while `Flux#flatMap` is a asynchronous operation which can be handled by many threads. and also leverages the inner webflux eventloop. I'd be curious to see some benchmarks here.

Comment: Understand your comments but the `stream#map` is only used to build a list of `Monos` and could be taken out.. The `Mono.zip` is what executes all the `ChipDetail` requests asynchronously. How exactly is differs from Flux is interesting to me too though I'm going on the assumption that it is a somewhat more efficient.